# The fragment layout isn't displaying at runtime using FragmentContainerView()

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

I used the `<FragmentContainerView>` for my fragment and used the `android:name=""` attribute to add a fragment activity file

```
    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container_content"
        android:name="com.nspinto.recordkeeper.RunningFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottom_nav"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_running" />
```

The text displays fine in the preview after adding `tools:layout="@layout/fragment_runnning` but the FragmentContainerView shows up blank at runtime when the app opens up initially

I checked the implementations and retyped the code block allowing android studio to fill in the `android:name=""` and `tools:layout=""` from the Problem suggestions.

I checked the fragment activity too but I don't think the problem was there because the fragment works fine on click and switches between different fragments with no problems it just doesn't display the first fragment on opening the app.

I'm not getting any errors or warnings either so I'm kinda lost on why it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

if you're trying to work with navigation component ! You need to change parent from **androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView** to simple **fragment**

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragmentContainerView"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/smoothBar"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />
```